# Android: go to a custom screen in Phone settings

Tags: android

I have a rooted version of android, which has a custom settings option 'screen' to set the screen resolution. Now I would like to go to that particular screen directly from my app on a button click.
It is not possible to set it using Settings class of android, as it does not a standard screen
present in Custom Android devices.

Is there anyway I can go to the 'screen' option directly from my app?

Comment: Obviously, you have a custom ROM, which may support this.  It's likely that you'll need to pass some values in the intent to invoke the settings - but the only way to find out would be to look at the source of your settings app.

Comment: @AleksG: Actually I have an option below 'Display' named 'Screen' which lets you set the screen resolution.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  In order for you to understand how (or indeed whether it's possible) to go directly to it, you will need to go through the source code of the settings app on you specific ROM.

Comment: @AleksG: Please post your comment as an answer, I did what you suggested and it worked, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a custom ROM, naturally, your Settings app is also custom-made for it.  It's likely that you can do what you want by passing some values in the intent to start the Settings app.  What those values should be can be determined by looking at the source code of the Settings app on your ROM.